# Puma gem does not build with Pakyow new blog

Tags: pakyow

I am trying to get Pakyow project built, but the build stops at (gem) Puma error. I am curious how Pakyow got beyond this Puma error? Basically the gem install puma does not build/bundle.

Comment: Hello! What platform are you running on? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Answer (score 0):

## Installing Puma on Windows

I found these steps at https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows. From there, you can find links to libraries and programs.

1. Install DevKit for your Ruby version, e.g. in `c:\devkit`
2. Download and unpack the OpenSSL Package, e.g. in `c:\openssl` (use 7Zip or PeaZip)
3. Copy the DLLs from the bin directory (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`) to your `ruby/bin` directory.
4. Open a Windows console/command prompt
5. Initialize the DevKit build environment by changing directory to the directory you installed DevKit `cd \devkit` and running the batch file `devkitvars.bat`
6. Install the puma gem with the OpenSSL packages `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl`
7. Verify in command prompt with `puma -v`

Comment: no luck. the 64 bit version did not compile the gem. I tried to use the 64 bit version of Puma and it has labeled 32 bit versions of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. I was hoping to find a libeay64.dll and ssleay64.dll on the internet to try, but no such luck in finding 64 bit openssl with anything other than 32 bit of those files.

Answer (score 0):

skylenewman's suggestion worked for my. I have a Windows 7 32-bit OS.

I also tried this on a Win7 64-bit and was hitting errors on puma gem installation. I'm not sure if it's a directory structure issue as I put the /devkit and /openssl on the F: drive instead of C:.